# Writing a script to convert my csv info to JSON format

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, csv

I have csv of country data with 2 pieces information and im trying to convert it to json format and store it in a variable. Could someone help me write a script in ruby or JS to make it happen?!

Currently data is in my spread sheet csv like this:

```
code              data

AW                12.78

AD                67.45

AF                95.62

AO                12.10

AL                50.52
```

And I'd like to get it to a format like this:

```
var countryData = {
  "AW": 12.78,
  "AD": 67.45,
  "AF": 95.62,
  "AO": 12.10,
  "AL": 50.52
};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to create a solution yourself yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the data in a file called *a.csv* :

```
code data

AW 12.78

AD 67.45

AF 95.62

AO 12.10

AL 50.52
```

Required stdlibs are [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) and [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

I'd do as below using those libs.

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

array = []
```

Here **row** is an instance of the class [`CSV::Row`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html). Now `row['code']`,`row['data']` are actually a method call [`CSV::Row#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-5B-5D).

```
CSV.foreach("/home/kirti/workspace/Ruby/a.csv",:skip_blanks => true,:headers => true,:col_sep => " ") do |row|
   array << [row['code'],row['data'].to_f]
end

puts Hash[array].to_json
# >> {"AW":12.78,"AD":67.45,"AF":95.62,"AO":12.1,"AL":50.52}
```

You will get all information about the options(**:skip_blanks**,**:headers**,**:col_sep**), I used here, below the documentation of [`CSV::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new). Read those.

Comment: Your code above works 100%, but does it really help the user giving them an out and out answer when we've seen no attempt of their own?

Comment: @steiger may be OP never used CSV, so I tried to help him, to show how to proceed.

Comment: I have never used it before so thank you for being thorough in your explanation! I will be doing this many times with different data sets so will be applying the info you shared. Thanks!